# Draw grid, follow mouse

Tags: java

I need to create a 10*10 grid on the interactions window of white squares. I then need to draw a square in the middle, and have the square follow the mouse. Once the square passes a box on the grid, change the color of that box and then move the square according to that color:

○ White: ​square moves towards the mouse

○ Blue: ​square moves away from the mouse

○ Green: ​square moves in a random direction

○ Red: ​square does not move at all

My question is, how do I allocate grid so that it knows when the square has passed through one of its indexes?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  StdDraw.setScale(0, 100);

  int[][] grid = new int[10][10];
  int gridState = 0;
  int antCoord = 0; 
  int mouseCoord = 0;

  moveAnt(gridState, antCoord, mouseCoord);

  while (true)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
      {
        StdDraw.filledSquare(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY(), 1);
      }
   }
  } // end of main

   public static int moveAnt(int gridState, int antCoord, int mouseCoord)
   {
     double mouseMoveX = StdDraw.mouseX();
     double mouseMoveY = StdDraw.mouseY();
     if (StdDraw.mousePressed())
     {
       StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
       StdDraw.filledSquare(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY(),  1);
      }

     if (mouseMoveX == mouseMoveX+1)
      {
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
        StdDraw.filledSquare(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY(), 1);
       }
     return antCoord;
     } // end of moveAnt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "moves away from the mouse"? where exactly should it move? Also, how do you define what color will have the square that the mouse pointer just hovered?

Comment: it moves away 1 grid space. The squares that the mouse just hovered should change once the square passes it.